# The meaning of a sentence

Tags: meaning

> "I make my way through each day, having lots of fun".

What does "make my way through each day" mean here?

Comment: It's a general term for getting by, find a route for your needs, figuring out how to survive.  Google it and you'll see.

Comment: *Navigating* through a period of life is a metaphor for *living* through that period, perhaps with more deliberateness.

Answer (score 1):

It means: "get by", "journey", "travel", "experience", "navigate", etc....

example:

> I *experience* each day, having lots of fun

It's just a metaphor in English that has come to mean, "the process of experiencing or navigating that time period".